# How to avoid bundling build outputs for each environment separately

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple repositories, each with separate build. In VSTS release tasks, I bundle the build outputs into single ZIP, that I then deploy to multiple environments:

[image]

For the bundling I have created Task Group that I share among all environments, but it is not necessary to bundle it again and again for each environment.

It is possible to bundle it once and deploy to all environments?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, when your release starts, VSTS will download all build artifacts to a single directory for your use inside the release tasks.  I see no reason why you'd want to then Zip this output up per environment.  Could you explain more what this zip file contains, and why you feel you need it?

Comment: I have multiple builds, each with its own output. I need to combine the outputs into single zip and I do this in release. You are right, that I don't need to do it for each environment and that's what I'm asking

Comment: Why you need to zip all in one? You can add multiple artifacts. Please clarify a little more on that.

Answer (score 0):

- If each environment run on **different agent machines**, you should bundle build artifacts in each environment separately.
- If all the environments run on the **same agent machine** and if it’s ok for you to run all the environments sequentially, you can bundle build artifacts in the first environment, and then use the bundled artifacts in the following environments directly. Detail steps for changing the release definition as below:

  1. Set Staging environment’s pre-deployment conditions

     Select Development environment for After environment option, so that after deploying Development environment, Staging environment will be triggered.

     [image]

     [image]
  2. Select skip download of artifacts option for the following environments

     If you bundle the artifacts in Development environment, you should select skip download of artifacts option for the following environments (as Staging and Production environment in your case).

     [image]